# add alt text to images loaded from json with media_sideload_image

Tags: images

I am using media_sideload_image() to save images from a json feed

is there a way to attach alt text to the images?

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the attachment ID you can add alt text by setting the `_wp_attachment_image_alt` post meta for the attachment:

```
update_post_meta( $attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', 'Alt text here' );
```

To get the attachment ID from [`media_sideload_image()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_sideload_image/) you can set the 4th argument to `'id'`:

```
$attachment_id = media_sideload_image( $file, $post_id, $desc, 'id' );

if ( ! is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', 'Alt text here' );
}
```